# Use of the possessive

Tags: double-possessive

Is the possessive apostrophe "s" added to family?  "I am a friend of Conor's and his family.    vs  I am a friend of Conor's and his family's?

Answer (score 2):

The preposition *of* already denotes possession or association, so it is not necessary to write *Conor's* as well. "I am a friend of Conor and his family" would be correct.

Comment: +1 And if the apostrophe is to be used, drop the *of* and put it only on the last item. (*I am Conor and his family's friend.*)